# Category +load timing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, swizzling

I have a class hierarchy as follows

```
@interface PTLDatasource : NSObject
...
@interface PTLFetchedDatasource : PTLDatasource
...
```

And I want to add platform specific extensions to these classes that are defined in a protocol and implemented in a category:

```
@protocol PTLTableViewDatasource
- (void)foo;
...
@interface PTLDatasource (TableViewExtensions) <PTLTableViewDatasource>
...
@interface PTLFetchedDatasource (TableViewExtensions) <PTLTableViewDatasource>
...
```

A basic implementation of `-foo:` is done in the PTLDatasource category.  However, I also need a custom implementation of `-foo:` in PTLFetchedDatasource which may then fallback to the PTLDatasource implementation.

Currently I'm trying to swizzle the implementations in `PTLFetchedDatasource (TableViewExtensions)` in `+load`, but I'm running into issues where `+load` in `PTLFetchedDatasource (TableViewExtensions)` is called before `+load` in `PTLDatasource (TableViewExtensions)`, so swizzling fails because the PTLDatasource implementation of `-foo:` doesn't exist yet.

Is there a way to work around this load timing issue?

Do I even need swizzling?  I know that overriding class member methods in a category is a no-no, but could I just call `[super foo:]` from the `PTLFetchedDatasource (TableViewExtensions)` implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Ash confirmed for me that swizzling is unnecessary and I can just call through to super.  The only concern with overriding the category method would be if it was done multiple times on the same class.